# Marklogic - range query using xdmp:document-timestamp

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to search all documents between 2 dates using xdmp:document-timestamp.

Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail? We generally prefer questions which show some effort, as this also helps see where exactly you got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

The timestamp property of documents is not indexed, so using that to limit search results would be very expensive. Use the last-modified property instead, or add your own element/property for that goal, apply a date or dateTime range index on it, and use element-range-queries to constrain your searches.

HTH!